# Problemas con el <mat-sidenav> Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Hola gente vengo aca porque tengo un inconveniente y es que al momento de usa
mat-sidenav en mi codigo no me muestra el contenido la pagina se me queda en blanco siento que es esa etiqueta especifica porque si la cambio por un mat-sidenav-content si me muestra el contenido de la pagina pero no lo muestra como lo quiero estoy siguiendo un curso de Vaxi dejo mi codigo por aca a ver si me pueden ayudar a resolver ese problema

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav [opened]="abrirMenu">
  <P>HOLAAAAA</P>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
  <button (click)="abrirMenu">ABRIR</button>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

también dejo un error que me deja la consola que no entiendo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quedo atento y de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paso 1:** Habilitar el módulo de animaciones.

Importar **`BrowserAnimationsModule`**, que introduce las capacidades de animación en su módulo de aplicación de raíz angular.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```